hide and unhide interactive grid in oracle apex
In a page, I want add two interactive grids and one page item.
based the data given in the page item I want hide one interactive grid and want to show other.
how does can I make it work.
any dynamic action needs to add or any other procedure.

One option is to create server side condition for the interactive grid region.
Presuming that item is a select list item which returns two values:
select 'Grid 1' d, 1 r from dual union all
select 'Grid 2' d, 2 r from dual

Its "Page action on selection" should be submit (if it is a safe action, i.e. grids aren't editable) or redirect and set value.
Server side condition might be a function body (for the 1st grid):
return :P1_ITEM = 1;

(similarly for the 2nd grid).

Another option is to create dynamic action on the select list item which has two actions for every region:

Show - region 1

set client side condition to:

type: item = value
item: P1_ITEM
value: 1




Hide - region 1

set client side condition to:

type: item != value
item: P1_ITEM
value: 1





Do the same for the 2nd region.
